# Add action to an AnnotationPin in swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've made a "classic" map on swift, with the user location and some AnnotationPin. I use the default look for iOS 11 so when I click on a Pin, it gets bigger. The name and subname are also displayed below the pins.

My question is : **How do I add an action so that if I click on a Pin, I go to another page to display stuffs ?** Maybe I could replace this "zoom" on the pin or add my action there, but I don't know how (I'm a beginner).

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mapView's `didSelect` delegate method.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheMoon", sender: self)
}
```

See also [How to perform segue programmatically in Xcode 8 : Swift 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD02mR8UpRk)